# Set display options for more than one layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-pro, multi-band

I am trying to set display options for more than one layer in the ArcGIS Pro software.
The task is to activate 3 raster layers at the same time in order to create a new pseudocolor map with bands.
I know that such can be done in the ArcMap via the Layer List in the Image Analysis window,
[image: Layer List]
but I cannot seem to find it in the Pro version.